# Sort CSV Records

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to sort a csv file on a specific column using batch scripting.

The csv file has about 22 column and column L(10) contains zip codes. There are multiple records with the same zip code and I need to sort these record in  ascending numerical order.

This is what I've done so far,

```
for /F "tokens=1-22 delims=," %%a in (test.csv) do (
   rem Define the sorting column in next line: %%a=1, %%b=2, etc...
   set "line["%%l"]=%%d,%%f,%%l"
)

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set line[') do echo %%b >> result2.txt
```

This is my result. It is removing records with duplicated zip code. I should see multiple row with the same zip code but with different names of course.

```
"John","Doe","12078" 
"John","Doe3","12095"  
"John","Doe5","12197"
```

OR  %%f in (*csv) do (
   SET CurrentFile=%%f
   SET /a NumLines=0

```
   For /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< !CurrentFile!') Do (
   Set /a NumLines=%%j




    (set row=%~1) & (set last=%~1)
   For /F "tokens=4-7 delims=," %%D in ('type !CurrentFile!') do (
        if not defined row (set row=%%D %%F) else (set last=%%D %%F)

    )
   echo.    
   echo. Filename: !CurrentFile! 
       echo. Record Count: !NumLines! 
       echo. First Record Name:!row! 
       echo. Last Record Name: !last! 

) >> Result.txt
```

) 
ENDLOCAL

Comment: for /F "tokens=1-22 delims=," %%a in (test.csv) do (
   rem Define the sorting column in next line: %%a=1, %%b=2, etc...
   set "line["%%l"]=%%d,%%f,%%l"
)

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set line[') do echo %%b >> result2.txt

Comment: `(for /F "usebackq tokens=1-22 delims=," %%a in ("test.csv") do @echo(%%l,%%f,%%d'%%d,%%f,%%l) | (for /F "tokens=1* delims='" %%X in ('sort') do @echo(%%Y)` (given `'` does not occur in the data...)

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-22 delims=," %%a in (test.csv) do (
   rem Define the sorting column in next *three lines*: %%a=1, %%b=2, etc...
   if not defined V%%~l set "V%%~l=1000"
   set /A "V%%~l+=1"
   set "line[%%~l!V%%~l!]=%%d,%%f,%%l"
)

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set line[') do echo %%b >> result2.txt
```

If there are multiple records with the same zip code, then it is necessary to identify each one of them. This solution uses a variable called `V<zip code>` as counter for each one of the records with the same zip code. Then, the *value* of such a variable is joined to the zip code itself in order to create a unique key for each record. The program assumes that there is a maximum of 999 records with the same zip code; if this value is not enough, just add a zero in `if not defined V%%~l set "V%%~l=1000"` line...

Comment: So my next step is to do this this on each file in my folder. I need to first sort the file on zip and then get first and last fullname, total rows and file name. So I have to combine to script. I was able to create a script that get record count, first and last name and file name, however the names are not sort based on their zip code. I added the code in my original question.

Comment: Was this answer useful to you? If so, I encourage you to select it as Best Answer and upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56588370.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "sortfile=%destdir%\sortfile.txt"

SET /a sortcol=3

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 rem full line in %%a
 SET "fullline=%%a"
 CALL :sub %%a
)
)>"%sortfile%"

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=+" %%a IN (' sort "%sortfile%"') DO (
 ECHO %%b
)
)>"%outfile%"

DEL "%sortfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:sub
IF %sortcol% neq 1 FOR /L %%z IN (2,1,%sortcol%) DO SHIFT
ECHO %1+%fullline%
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q56588370.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`. `%sortfile%` is simply a temporary file having whatever name you desire within reason.

Retrieve each line of your file, and assign its content to a variable `fullline`, then execute the subroutine `:sub` with each line, passing the entire line as a parameter. Since each line must be a comma-separated list of items which may either be a quoted string or a string which doesn't contain spaces or commas, it can be decoded by the subroutine, so all that is required is to `shift` the parameter-list (columnrequired - 1) times and the required sort-data is in `%1`.

output `%1` followed by a delimiter and the entire line originally read (parenthesising a series of statements and redirecting sends the data that normally appears on the screen to the redirection destination) into a temporary file, sort it and remove the data prefixed to each line using the chosen delimiter.

This way, more than one column could be chosen, and the data manipulated as required - for instance, locally "zip codes" are 4-digit (which *can* begin `0`) and other countries use other formats or the ever-popular extension code that might be applied to a ZIP can be recorded and processed.

Here's my test data:

```
"John","Doe","12345","moredata 1"
"John","Do, or not","12345","moredata 2"
"John","Doe 4","12344","moredata 3"
"John","Doe 5","12345","moredata 4"
"John","Doe 6","12345","moredata 5"
"John","Doe 7","12344","moredata 6"
```

and output:

```
"John","Doe 4","12344","moredata 3"
"John","Doe 7","12344","moredata 6"
"John","Do, or not","12345","moredata 2"
"John","Doe 5","12345","moredata 4"
"John","Doe 6","12345","moredata 5"
"John","Doe","12345","moredata 1"
```